# how to send data using post while reload page using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, post

I know to send data using get while reloading part of the page using jquery.

But i need to send data using post while reload the part of the page.Here is my code to reload the part of the page

```
$("#show").fadeOut('slow').load("listusers.php?data"+data).fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/),

> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.

So, assuming that `data` is a javascript object, you can post to `listusers.php` by simply passing it in:

```
$("#show").fadeOut('slow').load("listusers.php", data).fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: then how can get that object from php

Comment: You will be getting that objects keys as $_POST[key] in php :) Suppose your object is {name: 'John'} the you will get $_POST['name'] in php which will have a value 'John'

Comment: if call $("#show").load("listusers.php",data); the table is not reloading.iif i call like $("#show").load("listusers.php"); the table is reloading..what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

This will me more clean,

```
$("#show").fadeOut('slow', function() {
  //load after fadeout
   $.post("listusers.php",{Data:data},function(data){
       //fade in after load
      $("#show").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
   });
});
```

Comment: The documentation of $.get clearly says "Load data from the server using a HTTP GET request". And he is wants to use POST method, so maybe $.post instead of $.get will fit his need. :)